# Should an elseif statement have an else at the end?

Tags: php

I have the two conditions below. I don't need to check the second `if` if the first `if` returns true, but if it returns false check the second `if`. I don't need any of the `if` statements to return true so `if else` is not applicable

```
if($a > $b){
    //do this
}

if($a == $c){
    //do this
}
```

So I do the below. I try it on `localhost` and it works, but I'm not sure if its ok? The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) did not say anything about having an end `else` statement.

```
if($a > $b){
    //do this
} elseif ($a == $c){
    //do this
}
```

So is it ok or not?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be okay?

Comment: if you think that there could be the condition may come which may not be come in any of the `IF` condition that definitely you have to use `elseif`. It is good habit.

Comment: If it *works*, you obviously don't *need* an `else`. If your logic doesn't have an `else` case, then you obviously don't *need* an `else`.

Comment: it is not ok to program without understanding own code...

Comment: I don't get why hate on this question. What? Its not allowed to ask this in SO?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski that's why you ask to better understand your own code.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski That's how I learnt to program. By writing it and seeing what happens. It's not ok to do it commercially but otherwise if you won't tell the code police then neither will I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have as less `if-else` conditions as possible, esp. inside a loop. It is perfectly fine to not to have any `else` statements in the `if-elseif` constructs.

The code would skip the `if-elseif` block for all the conditions that don't match.

You may like to include the `else` block if you want to cover all the conditions that you have not covered in the `if-elseif` conditions. If not, it's fine!

Comment: That's a pretty bold statement with no justification. I would quite happily have more `if-else` statements everywhere, if it means less unnecessary code gets evaluated.

Comment: @GeorgeReith, IMHO there should be as less `if-else` code as possible. If there is no other choice then we should of course use them. I didn't mean that we should do away with `if-else`. We cannot do that. I hope this clarifies my point.

Comment: Not really, I don't see why `if-else` usage should be reduced compared to any other statement. You can optimise your statements so that they are more efficient. If anything you should reduce your usage of loops not `if-else` within loops. That's a dangerous thing to tell a newbie who may now shoot themselves in the foot attempting to avoid `if-else` statements.

Comment: @GeorgeReith, I agree to what you've written.

Answer (score 1):

If thats the case try using Switch statement

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score -1):

```
if($a > $b){
    //do this
$z=true or false;
if($z||($a == $c)){
    //do this
}
return $z;

}
```

Dont directly return your true or false just put it in one variable and check your condition with that variable inside first condition then return your variable.
it will work.